# Freeware personal wiki on desktop & mobile using plaintext?

Tags: windows, android, wiki, windows-mobile

I'm looking for a freeware personal wiki with these additional criteria:

1. Use plaintext files for the wiki articles.
2. Have desktop Windows version, and mobile version (Windows Mobile or Android).
3. Can be used in portable mode on USB memory sticks.
4. Use simple Wiki markup (better still legible text Markdown format).
5. Provide autogenerated TOC of sections in wiki articles.
6. Still under active development.

I currently use Dale Lane's bLADE Wiki, that meets all the criteria above except #6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meeting some of the requirements is [Ema Personal Wiki](http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/ema-personal-wiki-for-android-and.html).

A disclaimer: it's my own app :)

Comment: Thanks Jan Willem B. I think your Ema Personal Wiki meets my requirements 1, 2, 3, 4, & 6; but not requirement 5. It's certainly in my list of personal wiki to consider if further development improves it, even though it's shareware. I'm still holding out for a freeware one. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [VimWiki plugins](http://code.google.com/p/vimwiki) for a while now. Now, if you are not familiar with Vim, perhaps try Tiddlywiki instead.

I use VimWiki this way:

1. I install Vim on my USB drive, so I can edit on the fly.
2. VimWiki manages wiki in plain text format but you can convert the entire wiki to HTML. Unfortunately, you might have to host your wiki to be viewable online via your phone.
3. Markup is simple, but not markdown. For instance, h1 would be `=Title=` and h2 would be `==title==`. `*bold*` and `_emphasize_`.
4. Have some math support, you are going to have to visit their Google Code group for more info.
5. Table of content? `%toc` at the beginning of article will insert table of content to the HTML file when converted.
6. Can use HTML templates, so if you need to add headers, it's no problem.
7. Oh another one that I love, `table!!` In plaintext, but it auto-aligns your table cells. The reason I started using this wiki.

And under development.

Of course the downside to this is vim. It's a steep learning curve so if you haven't used vim before, it might not be worth it to use this wiki.